# Splitting a string with ignore case

Tags: java

I would like to be able to split a string about "/", but not split if there is a "/".

For example,

```
String string = "abc/abc\\/abc/abc";
```

should give me

```
[abc, abc\/abc, abc]
```

instead of

```
[abc, abc\, abc, abc]
```

How can I do this? I know string.split("/") gives me the 2nd result.

Comment: What's the rule for when not to split? The escape character?

Comment: Yes. It should not split when there is the escape infront of /